# Highlights Epub open in UIWebView

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, highlighting, highlight, epub

Any one can help me out for highlighting on epub. I open epub on UIWebView and allow user to highlight the text which he can see in future too. I am having database to store highlights detail. I am able to highlight using javascript. But since it uses range etc it remain till page is not change or reload.

Those who donot know what is epub you can suggest me on simple html page.

Please any one can suggest me how to implement highlight just like ibook have

Any logics?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey Soniya !! did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: No still not get good solution. Till now i am using search and highlight technique allow user a long string only so that there is more chances for it to be unique. But when i will get solution i post it

Answer (score 0):

See the following for the Javascript required:

https://github.com/fedefrappi/AePubReader/blob/master/AePubReader/SearchWebView.js

Download entire project to see how it's used.

Comment: I have already look into this project and this javascript is for searching and highlighting. But I want to highlight the user chosen data which he could see highlighted any time when he visits that page